# Ruby merging items in array conditionally

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array containing capital and small letters. I am trying to concatenate capital letters with the following small letters in a new array. For example, I have the following array

```
first_array = ["A","b","C","d","e"]
```

and I want to obtain the following array

```
["Ab","Cde"] #new array
```

I am trying to iterate through the first array with a code that looks like this:

```
new_array = []
first_array.each_with_index do |a,index|
  if (a!~/^[a-z].*$/)
    new_array = new_array.push "#{a}"
  else
    new_array[-1] = first_array[index-1] + "#{a}" #the idea is to concatenate the small letter with the previous capital letter and replace the last item in the new array
  end
```

but it does not work. I am not sure I am tackling this issue efficiently which is why I can't resolve it. Could somebody suggest some options?

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: @Sergio - I do not get the right results. With the code above I get ["Ab","de"]

Comment: Put that info in the question.

Comment: Why the mad rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to split your original array when next char is uppercase, and then make strings of those subarrays? There's [a method in standard lib](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) that can help you here:

```
first_array = ["A","b","C","d","e"]
result = first_array.slice_when do |a, b|
  a_lower = a.downcase == a
  b_upper = b.upcase == b
  a_lower && b_upper
end.map(&:join)

result # => ["Ab", "Cde"]
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. This is the closest from what I am looking for but I would like "result" to be an array not a string.

Comment: @Bastien: how so? You have array of strings as desired result in the question. This is what `result` is.

Answer (score 3):

If you join as a string you can then scan to get all the matches:

```
first_array.join.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*/)
=> ["Ab", "Cde"]
```

Comment: Do you know wich one, between your regex solution and the `slice_when` solution, is the more optimised ?

Comment: @Caillou, I'd be surprised if there were much of a difference, but to my eye this reads quite a bit better. Given the desired result, `join`, as a first step, seems natural.

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer @Paul's answer, you could do the following.

```
first_array.slice_before { |s| s.upcase == s }.map(&:join)
  #=> ["Ab", "Cde"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Sergio's answer a lot, here's what I brewed up while trying it out:

```
def append_if_present(lowercase, letters)
  lowercase << letters.join if letters.size > 0
end

first_array = ["A","b","C","d","e"]

capitals = []
lowercase = []
letters = []

first_array.each_with_index do |l, i|
  if l =~ /[A-Z]/
    capitals << l
    append_if_present(lowercase, letters)
    letters = []
  else
    letters << l
  end
end

append_if_present(lowercase, letters)

p capitals.zip(lowercase).map(&:join)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that uses [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) :

```
first_array.slice_when{ |a, b| b.upcase == b && a.downcase == a }.map(&:join)
```

Comment: I've never understood why people say, "here's a one-liner", followed by one line of code. :-). You don't need `.to_a`.

Comment: You're right for the `to_a`, thanks. What would you rather read instead of "Here's a one liner" ?

Comment: "Here's a method that uses [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when).

Comment: I guess you're right. I edited my comment with the documentaion link.